# Tracking down Segmentation Fault 11

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I understand that Segmentation Fault indicates I am attempting to access memory that I shouldn't/hasn't been allocated but can't find what is triggering this error in my code. Other answers have pointed towards using Valgrind however I do not have a compiler on my local machine and do not have administrative privilege to install it on the School Server. Any help pointing out where the error occurred would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the Header file

```
/*
 * File:        set.h
 *
 * Copyright:   2015, Darren C. Atkinson
 *
 * Description: This file contains the public function and type
 *              declarations for a set abstract data type for strings.  A
 *              set is an unordered collection of distinct elements.
 *
 *              Note that this file uses the bool type, but does not define
 *              it.  You should include <stdbool.h> beforehand.
 */

# ifndef SET_H
# define SET_H

typedef struct set 
{
    char **elts; //char * array containing strings
    int length; //total length of array
    int size; //number of strings within array
}SET;


SET *createSet(int maxElts);

void destroySet(SET *sp);

int numElements(SET *sp);

bool hasElement(SET *sp, char *elt);

bool addElement(SET *sp, char *elt);

bool removeElement(SET *sp, char *elt);

# endif /* SET_H */
```

The given test file to compile with my code.

```
/*
 * File:        unique.c
 *
 * Copyright:   2015, Darren C. Atkinson
 *
 * Description: This file contains the main function for testing a set
 *              abstract data type for strings.
 *
 *              The program takes two files as command line arguments, the
 *              second of which is optional.  All words in the first file
 *              are inserted into the set and the counts of total words and
 *              total words in the set are printed.  If the second file is
 *              given then all words in the second file are deleted from
 *              the set and the count printed.
 */

# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <stdbool.h>
# include "set.h"


/* This is sufficient for the test cases in /scratch/coen12. */

# define MAX_SIZE 18000


/*
 * Function:    main
 *
 * Description: Driver function for the test application.
 */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    SET *unique;
    int words;


    /* Check usage and open the first file. */

    if (argc == 1 || argc > 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s file1 [file2]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: cannot open %s\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    /* Insert all words into the set. */

    words = 0;
    unique = createSet(MAX_SIZE);

    while (fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer) == 1) {
        words ++;
        addElement(unique, buffer);
    }

    printf("%d total words\n", words);
    printf("%d distinct words\n", numElements(unique));
    fclose(fp);


    /* Try to open the second file. */

    if (argc == 3) {
        if ((fp = fopen(argv[2], "r")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: cannot open %s\n", argv[0], argv[2]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }


        /* Delete all words in the second file. */

        while (fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer) == 1)
            removeElement(unique, buffer);

        printf("%d remaining words\n", numElements(unique));
    }

    destroySet(unique);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And finally my code which is where the error should be originating from.

```
/*
 * File:        unsorted.c
 *
 *
 * Description: This file contains the definitions for a simple interface for a SET structure that contains a list of strings as well as the list size.
 */
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "set.h"

int findElement(SET *sp,char *elt);

struct SET
{
    char **elts; //char * array containing strings
    int length; //total length of array
    int size; //number of strings within array
};

//initializes SET
//O(1) efficiancy
SET *createSet(int maxElts)
{
    SET *sp; 
    sp->elts = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char*)*maxElts);
    assert(sp->elts!=NULL);
    sp->size = 0;
    sp->length = maxElts;
    return sp;
}

//frees all strings from memory and then the containing array
//O(n) efficiancy n==sp->size
void destroySet(SET *sp)
{
    while (sp->size > 0) free(sp->elts[--sp->size]);
    free(sp->elts);
}

//return the number of strings within the array
//O(1) efficiency
int numElements(SET *sp)
{
    return sp->size;
}

//Sequentially searches SET for elt and return the array location, if not found -1 is returned
//O(n) efficiency n=sp->size
int findElement(SET *sp,char *elt)
{
    int i =0;
    for (i; i < sp->size; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(sp->elts[i],elt) == 0) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

//appends elt on the end of the array within SET
//O(1) efficiency
bool addElement(SET *sp, char *elt)
{
    if (findElement(sp, elt) != -1) return false;
    if (sp->size == sp->length) return false;
    sp->elts[sp->size] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(elt)+1));
    assert(sp->elts[sp->size]!=NULL);
    sp->size = sp->size +1;
    return true;
}

//returns true if SET contains elt otherwise return false
//O(n) efficiency n=sp->size
bool hasElement(SET *sp, char *elt)
{
    if (findElement(sp,elt) == -1) return true;
    return false;
}

//finds elt and removes it from array if present, then moves all following strings forward in the array
//O(n) efficiency n=sp->size
bool removeElement(SET *sp,char *elt)
{
    int loc = findElement(sp,elt);
    if (loc == -1) return false;
    free(sp->elts[loc]);
    while (loc <sp->size)
    {
        sp->elts[loc] = sp->elts[loc+1];
        loc++;
    }
    sp->size=sp->size-1;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should probably figure how to install a compiler (you might already have one) and valgrind.

Comment: If you have only remote compilation and execution facilities to rely upon, then you can try pruning back your program bit by bit to reduce it to the smallest possible program that exhibits the problem.  Oftentimes this exercise will help you discover the nature of the problem, but even if it does not, the result will be just the sort of [mcve] that we look for here.

Comment: With `(fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer)` , why not limit to `(fscanf(fp, "%XXXs", buffer)`  or whatever `BUFISZE -1 ` might be?

Comment: Look at `createSet()`... you're assigning values to members of a struct you haven't created... (do something with `sp` before you mess with `sp->elts`, etc.)

Comment: @Dmitri is right. Also please do not cast malloc's return value. It doesn't accomplish anything and you risk errors that are a true pain in the ass to debug.

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri that was the issue

Comment: The header file uses the contents of stdbool.h, so a `#include <stdbool.h>`  statement should be near the top of the header file

Comment: this statement has a problem:  `for (i; i < sp->size; i++)`  suggest using: `for ( ; i < sp->size; i++)`

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: the `assert()` function is 'ok' for debugging, but a very bad idea for production code.

Answer (score 0):

in function: createSet(),

the variable sp is not initialized to point to an instance of the struct set.

so the code should be similar to this:

```
SET *sp = NULL; 
if( NULL == (sp = malloc( sizeof( struct set ) ) ) 
{ 
    perror( "malloc for struct set failed" ); 
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); 
}
```

Otherwise sp will contain what ever random address is on the stack at it's location.

This is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: This is some obscure code. Any reason why you wouldn't write `SET* sp = malloc (...); if(sp == NULL) { ...`?

Comment: @Lundin, this kind of statement is very commonly used and it helps to inhibit later maintainers of the code from separating the allocation from the error checking.

Comment: No, it isn't commonly used. And there is no reason why you would want to keep allocation and error checking mixed up in the same expression. If you have written `SET* sp = malloc (...); if(sp == NULL) ` and then some retard later on decides to add branching code between those two statements, there is nothing you can do to help them, because they are too incompetent to maintain C code in the first place. There is no reason to obfuscate your code just because you suspect that incompetent people will maintain it. Instead, assume that your code will be maintained by competent C programmers.

Comment: @Lundin,   "assume that your code will be maintained by competent C programmers"  A very unreliable assumption.   I have been programming for over 40 years.  I have seen code to cause shudders, I have seen code that should have been an embarrassment to the programmer that originally wrote it and or maintained it.  As little as 4 years ago, I had to maintain code that was written as though the original programmer just slapped some code down as they happened to think of it.

Comment: Then I'm sure you are aware that assignment inside if statements is bad practice and should be avoided, because it contains a side-effect and because they could get mixed up with ==. In the 80s it was recognized that this was a problem, so people started to use the so-called "yoda conditions" and write obfuscated code like `if(NULL == x)`, preventing this bug but at the same time making their code less readable. This problem was solved in 1989 when Borland added a compiler warning "possible incorrect assignment" if you used assignment inside if statements, rendering this style obsolete.

Comment: If compiler warnings from the year 1989 aren't modern enough, there's always MISRA-C:2012, banning assignment inside if statements, since they consider it dangerous practice.

Comment: I stated the code should be *similar to* the example I posted.  No one has to copy it.  Separating the assignment from the 'if' is perfectly ok.  Do any of you have an actual compliant that my answer is NOT the reason the OPs code is not working?